# Where is the value of 'x' coming from?

Tags: c++, libcurl

Using the following example code, 'x' holds the value of a URL without the URL ever being saved to it. How is this possible? 'X' is only used when it is being declared and when being used for cout.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

string x; //will hold the url's contents

int main()
{
    CURL* var; //our curl object

    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL); //pretty obvious
    var = curl_easy_init();

    curl_easy_setopt(var, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/path");

    curl_easy_perform(var);

    cout << endl << x << endl;
    cin.get();

    curl_easy_cleanup(var);
    curl_global_cleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tested the code ?

Comment: Yes, and it outputs the html right out to the console.

Comment: Change the `cout` line to `cout << "\nx = " << x << endl;`. It may be that one of the `curl_` functions is actually outputting the URL instead.

Comment: It does seem like a curl function is outputting it. I still have a lot to learn.

Comment: i enjoy using custom debug macros to avoid this problem - all of my intended debug output is prefixed in the same way, so there is a very good chance i can know its mine and not arbitrary output from something else without digging anywhere to check...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the curl_easy_perform() function that outputs the contents of that URL since it by default sends the output to stdout.

'x' is a global that is zeroed by default and thus outputs as nothing.